# At what level does the C-130 spawn at the airport in GTA online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

My friend (level 32) get's a C-130 every time he goes to mckenzie airfield but I don't.
Maybe it has something to do with the level you are in, but at what level does the C-130 Spawn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure your friend is a level 32?  From IGN it states the C-130 unlocks at Ranking 33.  [Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Unlockables_%28GTA_Online%29)

[image]

Comment: Your right, my friend was at level 33.